# Sonarqube LDAP authentication fails

Tags: ldap, authentication, sonarqube

I'm trying to install sonarqube 7.7 with ldap authentication against an active directory server and I can't get it to work. I copied over the settings from another server that runs on the same host, and its ldap settings work.

This is my current configuration in sonarqube:

```
ldap.url=ldap://myADserver.mydomain.local:389
ldap.bindDn="CN=myldapuser,OU=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=local"
# ldap.bindPassword=mypassword
ldap.authentication=simple
ldap.realm=mydomain.local
ldap.user.baseDn="OU=myadgroup,DC=mydomain,DC=local"
ldap.user.request="(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))"
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
```

If i provide a password, sonarqube shuts down during startup with this error message in web.log:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042F, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580
```

This message apparently means that the user is correct, but the password is incorrect. Yet the password works both in the other server and in ldapsearch.

If I comment out the password like above, sonarqube starts up, but can't authenticate ldap users. I **can** log in with the default admin user.

```
DEBUG web[AWqxWJwHqJPbGHfaAAAX][o.s.p.l.LdapUsersProvider] User mypersonaluser not found in <default>
ERROR web[AWqxWJwHqJPbGHfaAAAX][o.s.s.a.CredentialsExternalAuthentication] Error during authentication
org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapException: Unable to retrieve details for user mypersonaluser in <default>
Caused by: javax.naming.directory.InvalidSearchFilterException: invalid attribute description
DEBUG web[AWqxWJwHqJPbGHfaAAAX][auth.event] login failure [cause|Unable to retrieve details for user mypersonaluser in <default>][method|FORM][provider|REALM|LDAP][IP|server_internal_IP|office_pub_IP][login|mypersonaluser]
```

For completeness sake the config of the other server and the ldapsearch comandline:

```
base = "OU=myadgroup,DC=mydomain,DC=local", 
bind_dn = "CN=myldapuser,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=local",
host = "myADserver.mydomain.local", 
label = "ldap", 
method = "plain", 
password = "mypassword", 
port = 389, 
uid = "sAMAccountName"

ldapsearch -D "cn=myldapuser,cn=users,DC=mydomain,DC=local" -p 389 -h myADserver.mydomain.local -b "OU=myadgroup,DC=mydomain,DC=local"  "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=mypersonaluser))" -u myldapuser -w mypassword
```

What's wrong with my sonarqube configuration and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

---

Looks like you have you password field commented out #?

```
# ldap.bindPassword=mypassword
```

You also don't need "" around the parameters

Unless your server allows anonymous access to the LDAP directory, you need to set bindBn and bindPassword

```
# Bind DN is the username of an LDAP user to connect (or bind) with.
ldap.bindDn=cn=user,OU=ou,DC=mycompany,DC=local
 
# Bind Password is the password of the user to connect with.
ldap.bindPassword=secret
```